# How does 'defining a method' work semantically?

Tags: ruby, class, object, methods, object-model

### Background:

Here is what I understand about the object model (relative to my question below):

- `self` always references the receiver in the current stack frame.
- When you are in the top level and you say `def someMethod` the implicit receiver is `self` and you are creating a method which sits in the anonymous class associated with `self`. This anonymous class happens to sit just under `Object` (`self` is an instance of the `Object` class) so when you call `someMethod`, Ruby "takes a step to the right", and it lands in the anonymous class, thus finding and invoking your method.
- This is similar to what goes on when you define methods inside of class definitions. If, when inside a class definition, you say: `def self.classMethod` you are creating a method in an anonymous class that sits just underneath the `Class` class. Methods of this class, existing "to the right" of the class currently being defined will not be visible to instances of the new class.

---

### My Question:

**How does "defining a method in a class" happen in the  first place?** (semantically)

`Class` objects aren't supposed to be different from normal objects, right?

From what I understand about message handling, `Class` objects have a table as a part of their state, presumable meaning it is an instance variable, that has the names of all of its instance methods. This is how the method look up works. (If Ruby doesn't find it , it goes up one and again, presumably the directions to the next link up the chain are a part of the state of the current `Class` object.)

Since Ruby doesn't really care about object type, I presume it doesn't care that it's looking in `Class` objects specifically when doing method look up. Rather, it's just following references and looking for bits of state with certain names.  So, could I create my own "class objects" without using the class keyword that don't inherit from the `Class` class?

If that question doesn't make any sense, then I apologize. I just want to know **what happens when the interpreter encounters the `def` keyword**.

Comment: What would a class object that doesn't inherit from `Class` be? Isn't that what any other object is?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes. That's why I put it in double quotes. I was asking if you can create a normal object that behaves like a`Class` object and was implicitly asking what would be involved in doing so..... again, this was just in an attempt to understand what it really means to "define a method"

Comment: You can create a class object with `Class.new(superclass = nil)` and if you examine `Class.new.class.superclass` you can determine that `Class` inherits from [`Module`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html) - which is where it gets most of its capabilities from.

Comment: You could most likely extend `Module` to create a class like object if you really wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write 'def something' in ruby you are adding a method to a module. Sometimes that module is a 'class' (a type of module). It all depends on what 'self' is at the time:

```
class Foo

  # right now self is 'Foo'

  class << self
    # right now self is 'Class:Foo'
  end

  def self.bar
    # right now self is 'Foo'
  end

end

def Foo.buz
  # right now self is 'Foo'
end

obj = Foo.new

def obj.baz
  # right now self is 'Foo:0x007fe8a632fa78' (an instance)
end
```

A class is just a type of module. Subclassing is one way of creating a pointer from One module up to another:

```
class Foo
end

class Bar < Foo
end

> Bar.ancestors
=> [Bar, Foo, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Another way is including mixins:

```
module Mixin
end
class Foo
  include Mixin
end

> Foo.ancestors
=> [Foo, Mixin, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Method dispatch works on what exists in the inheritance chain. It's a list (not a tree) of parent modules and is ordered based on when the inheritance was created:

```
# bar.rb

module MixinA
  def something
    puts "MixinA"
    super
  end
end

module MixinB
  def something
    puts "MixinB"
  end
end

class Base
  def something
    puts "Base"
    super
  end
end

class Sub < Base
  include MixinB
  include MixinA
  def something
    puts "Sub"
    super
  end
end

obj = Sub.new
obj.something
```

Run:

```
$ ruby bar.rb
Sub
MixinA
MixinB
```

Inspecting the chain:

```
> Sub.ancestors
=> [Sub, MixinA, MixinB, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

When a method call happens in walks this list looking for the method in question. If none of the modules in the chain have the method then the search starts over at the top but instead calls **method_missing**. In either case, the first resolution found wins.

Yehuda Katz wrote a good article on this stuff in 2009:

- http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/